# Using generalized logistic curve to create a mathematical model from data.

Tags: statistics, functions, mathematical-modeling, logistic-regression

[image]

The first row is time and the second row is height of a plant. We need to use generalized logistic curve to model the behavior of the plant. The equation of the logistic curve is :
$$N = \frac{N_*}{1+(N_*/N_0-1)e^{-a_0t}}$$ where $N_*$ is the maximum height of the plant or in other words, the supremum of the logistic function.

$a_0$ is how fast the function increases. My question is the following:

I know how to determine $N_*$, we just make up a number that is above $251$ and less than $251 + (251 - 247) $. But how to exactly determine $a_0$. I am quite lost here. How I would do it is to calculate every $a_0$ for every time and height, with equation $a_0 = \frac{1}{t}\ln(\frac{N}{N_0})$. In this equation $N$ would be the difference between heights, so let's say between $18$ and $33$ the $N$ for time equals $1$ would be $33 - 18$. Is the process here of creating a table of $\sum_{k = 1}^{10}(10 - i)$ column elements of differences, so that we take multiple $N_0$ until we run out of data from the primary table in the picture (so until $N_0 = 9$). Then we can use a formula for $a_0 = \frac{\sum a_{0l}*t_l}{\sum t_l}$ where $l$ is the number of elements.

Is my procedure for creating a logistic out of the data provided correct?

Comment: Isn't $N_0$ supposed to represent the value of $N(t)$ at time $t=0$? Note that $$18=N(0)=\left.N(t)\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{N_{\ast}}{1+(N_{\ast}/N_0-1)e^{-a_0t}}\right|_{t=0}=N_0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: One degree of freedom

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\pderiv}[2]{{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2} }}$
Have you considered using the *Method of Least Squares* to find $a_0$? For that method you can define an *error function* $$e(t_n)\eqd N(t_n)-y_n\eqd \frac{N_{*}}{1+\brs{N_{*}/N_0-1}e^{-a_0t_n}}-y_n$$ and a *cost function* (the error cost) as the *norm* squared of $e(t_n)$ as $$cost(a_0)\eqd\norm{e}^2\eqd\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}e^2(t_n)$$ You want to find the $a_0$ that minimizes that cost; that is, you want to find where (with respect to $a_0$) the cost function "goes to the lowest point". Suppose you set $N_0\eqd N(0)=18$ and $N_*\eqd252$ $\ldots$[image]From the plot, it appears that $cost(a_0)$ is minimized around $a_0=0.65$.

To get a more accurate optimal $a_0$, we can differentiate $cost(a_0)$ with respect to $a_0$ and set the expression to $0$. To do that, this (lemma) may come in handy:
$$\begin{align}
\boxed{N'(t)}
  &\eqd \pderiv{}{a_0}N(t)
\\&\eqd \pderiv{}{a_0}\brs{\frac{N_{*}}{1+\brp{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0t}}}
  && \text{by definition of $N(t)$}
\\&= \frac{0-N_*\brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0t}(-t)}{\brp{1+\brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0t}}^2}
  && \text{by Quotient Rule}
\\&= \frac{N_*^2}{\brp{1+\brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0t}}^2}
\brs{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}te^{-a_0t}
\\&\eqd \boxed{\brs{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}N^2(t)te^{-a_0t}}
&& \text{by definition of $N(t)$}
\end{align}$$
Then$\ldots$
$$\begin{align}
\boxed{0}&= \frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\cdot0
\\&=\frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\pderiv{}{a_0}\norm{e}^2
\\&\eqd \frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\pderiv{}{a_0}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}e^2(t_n)
  && \text{by definition of $\norm{\cdot}$}
\\&\eqd \frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\pderiv{}{a_0}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}^2
  && \text{by definition of $e$}
\\&= \frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}2\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}N'(t_n)
  && \text{by Chain Rule}
\\&= \frac{1}{2\brp{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}2\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}\brs{\frac{1}{N_0}-\frac{1}{N_*}}N^2(t_n)te^{-a_0t_n}
  && \text{by (lemma)}
\\&= \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}N^2(t_n)\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}t_ne^{-a_0t_n}}
\\&\eqd Dcost(a_0) 
  && \text{(call the sum $Dcost(a_0)$)}
\end{align}$$
Plotting $Dcost$ with respect to $a_0$, it appears that $Dcost(a_0)$ crosses $0$ at around $a_0=0.66$:[image]

The [uniroot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/uniroot) function from the R [stats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2) package indicates that $Dcost(a_0)$ crosses $0$ at $a_0=0.6631183$ with estim.prec=6.103516e-05.

Using $N_0\eqd18$, $N_*\eqd252$, and $a_0\eqd0.6631183$, $N(t)$ seems to fit the 11 data points fairly well ($cost(0.6631183)=31.32307$) $\ldots$
[image]

Some *R* code supporting [Reproducible Research](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/g/files/sbiybj6031/f/EFS%20NSF%20474.pdf):

```
#---------------------------------------
# packages
#---------------------------------------
#install.packages("stats");
 require(stats);
 rm(list=objects());

#---------------------------------------
# Data
#---------------------------------------
 tn = c(0:10)
 yn = c(18,33,56,90,130,170,203,225,239,247,251)
 t  = seq( from=min(tn), to=max(tn), length=1000 )

#---------------------------------------
# Estimate Function N(t)
#---------------------------------------
 N0=18
 Nh=252
 N = function(t,a) Nh / (1 + (Nh/N0-1)*exp(-a*t))

#---------------------------------------
# Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 cost = function(x,tn,yn) 
 {
  #sum((N(tn,x)-yn)^2)
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:11))
   { 
     summ = summ + (N(tn[i],x)-yn[i])^2
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 Dcost = function(x) 
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:11))
   { 
     summ = summ + (N(tn[i],x))^2 * (N(tn[i],x)-yn[i]) * tn[i]*exp(-x*tn[i])
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Find 0 crossing
#---------------------------------------
 x=seq(from=0.3, to=0.9, length=1000)
 aRoot = uniroot( Dcost, c(0.3, 0.9) )
 a0 = aRoot$root

#---------------------------------------
# Graphics
#---------------------------------------
 colors = c( "red" , "blue", "orange", "green"    );
 traces = c( "N(t)", "data", "cost"  , "Dcost"    ); 
 plot ( t , N(t, a0)      , col=colors[1], lwd=2, type='l', xlab="t", ylab="y", ylim=c(0,max(yn)+10) ) 
 lines( tn, yn            , col=colors[2], lwd=3, type='p' )
 lines( t , Dcost(t)      , col=colors[4], lwd=2, type='l' )
 lines( t , cost(t,tn,yn) , col=colors[3], lwd=2, type='l' )
 legend("topleft", legend=traces, col=colors, lwd=3, lty=1:1)
 grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @DanielJ.Greenhoe is very complete but it plays along with the initial premisse that you just pick $N_*$ in a compatible way. However, there is no reason why the minimisation process is not performed for the parameters $(N_*, a_0)$, instead of just $a_0$.

This leeds to the set of parameters $N_* = 255.844, a_0 = 0.65392$.

[image]

Comment: I would agree with PierreCarre that it would be better to optimize with respect to $(N_*,a_0)$
in $\Bbb{R}^2$ rather than selecting 
a "reasonable" value for $N_*$ and only optimizing with respect to $a_0$ in $\Bbb{R}^1$.
I'm adding two more methods below---one that optimizes with respect to $(N_*,a_0)$, 
yielding a result compatible with that of PierreCarre, 
and a third method that optimizes with respect to $(N_*,N_0,a_0)$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$.
I have also added a "Method 1..." title my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 2: Two degrees of freedom

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\pderiv}[2]{{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2} }}$
$\newcommand{\opair}[2]{\left( #1,#2\right)}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}$

Method 1 gave an expression for $\pderiv{}{a_0}N(t)$; here is a similar lemma for $\pderiv{}{N_*}N(t)$:
$$\begin{align*}
  \boxed{\pderiv{}{N_*}N(t)}
    &\eqd \pderiv{}{N_* }\brs{\frac{N_*}{1+\brp{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}}
    && \text{by definition of $N(t)$}
  \\&= \frac{\brs{1+\brp{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}} - N_*\brs{\frac{1}{N_0}}e^{-a_0 t}}
            {\brp{1+\brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}^2}
    && \text{by Quotient Rule}
  \\&= \frac{1 - e^{-a_0 t}}
            {\brp{1 + \brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}^2}
  \\&= \brs{\frac{1 - e^{-a_0 t}} {N_*^2}}
       \brs{\frac{N_*}                 {1 + \brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}}^2
  \\&\eqd \boxed{\brs{\frac{1 - e^{-a_0 t}}{N_*^2}} N^2(t)}
    && \text{by definition of $N(t)$}
\end{align*}
$$
Then$\ldots$
$$\begin{align*}
  \boxed{0}
    &= \frac{N_*^2}{2}\cdot0
  \\&=\frac{N_*^2}{2}
       \pderiv{}{N_*}\norm{e}^2
  \\&\eqd \frac{N_*^2}{2}
       \pderiv{}{N_*}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}e^2(t_n)
    && \text{by definition of $\norm{\cdot}$}
  \\&\eqd \frac{N_*^2}{2}
       \pderiv{}{N_*}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}^2
    && \text{by definition of $e$}
  \\&= \frac{N_*^2}{2}
       \sum_{n=0}^{n=10}2\brs{N(t_n)-y_n}\pderiv{}{N_h}N(t_n)
    && \text{by Chain Rule}
  \\&= N_*^2
       \sum_{n=0}^{n=10}  \brs{N(t_n)-y_n}
                          \brs{\frac{1 - e^{-a_0 t_n}}{N_h^2}} N^2(t_n)
    && \text{by lemma}
  \\&= \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{n=10} N^2(t_n) \brs{N(t_n)-y_n} \brs{1 - e^{-a_0 t_n} }}
\end{align*}$$

So now we have two equations in two unknowns ($N_*$ and $a_0$): $\pderiv{}{N_h}\norm{e}^2=0$ and $\pderiv{}{a_0}\norm{e}^2=0$ (from Method 1).
You can use a multi-root solver to find the solution $\opair{N_*}{a_0}$ to the equation pair
$\opair{\pderiv{}{N_h}\norm{e}^2=0}{\pderiv{}{a_0}\norm{e}^2=0}$.
The result using [multiroot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rootSolve/versions/1.8.2.1/topics/multiroot)
from the R package [rootSolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf)
is $\opair{N_*}{a_0}=\opair{255.8436595023}{0.6539203544}$.
This solution is "better" than Method 1 solution in the sense that it results in a lower *cost*:
$$\begin{array}{|c|rcl|}
  \text{Method} & cost(N_0,N_*,a_0)
\\\hline
\\1             & cost(18,252,0.6631183) &=& 31.32307
\\2             & cost(18,255.8436595023,0.6539203544) &=& 0.7140973
\end{array}$$

Some R code supporting [Reproducible Research](https://ropensci.github.io/reproducibility-guide/sections/introduction/):

```
 require(stats);
 require(R.utils);
 require(rootSolve);
 rm(list=objects());

#---------------------------------------
# Data
#---------------------------------------
 tdata = c(0:10)
 ydata = c(18,33,56,90,130,170,203,225,239,247,251)
 t     = seq( from=min(tdata), to=max(tdata), length=1000 )

#---------------------------------------
# Estimate Function N(t)
#---------------------------------------
 N0 = ydata[1]
 N = function(t,N0,Nh,a0)
 {
   result = Nh / ( 1 + (Nh/N0-1)*exp(-a0*t) )
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 cost = function(N0,Nh,a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) - ydata[i] )^2
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative with respect to a0 of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 Pcosta0 = function(N0, Nh, a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) )^2 *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) - ydata[i] ) *
                   ( tdata[i] * exp(-a0*tdata[i]) )
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative with respect to Nh of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 PcostNh = function(N0, Nh, a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( 1 - exp(-a0*tdata[i]) ) *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0) )^2 *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0)-ydata[i] )
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative vector of cost
#---------------------------------------
Pcost = function(x)
{
   N0 = 18
   Nh = x[1]
   a0 = x[2]
   F1 = Pcosta0( N0, Nh, a0 );
   F2 = PcostNh( N0, Nh, a0 );
   result = c(F1, F2);
}

#---------------------------------------
# Calculate roots
#---------------------------------------
 Roots = multiroot( f=Pcost, start=c(ydata[11-1],0.4) );
 Nh = Roots$root[1]
 a0 = Roots$root[2]

#---------------------------------------
# Display
#---------------------------------------
 printf("(N0, Nh, a0) = (%.2f, %.10f, %.10f) with estim.precis=%.2e\n", N0, Nh, a0, Roots$estim.precis )
 colors = c( "red" , "blue" );
 traces = c( "N(t)", "data" );
 plot ( t , N(t, N0, Nh, a0), col=colors[1], lwd=2, type='l', xlab="t", ylab="y", ylim=c(0,max(ydata)+10) )
 lines( tdata, ydata        , col=colors[2], lwd=5, type='p' )
 legend("topleft", legend=traces, col=colors, lwd=3, lty=1:1)
 grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 3: Three degrees of freedom

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\pderiv}[2]{{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2} }}$
$\newcommand{\opair}[2]{\left( #1,#2\right)}$
$\newcommand{\otriple}[3]{\left( #1,#2,#3\right)}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\esth}{N}$

**Method 1** optimized with respect to $a_0$ and
**Method 2** with respect to $\opair{N_*}{a_0}$.
Both methods assume $N_0\eqd y_n[0] \eqd 18$.
However, often in data modeling, it is assumed that
measured data is the actual true value being measured plus some
[*measurement noise*](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN1118210824).
As such, it is highly unlikely that the true height of the plant at time $t=0$
is exactly $y_n[0]=18.000\ldots$, but rather $18+n(0)$, where $n(0)$ is
a random noise variable at time $t=0$.

Method 1 gave a lemma for $\pderiv{}{a_0}N(t)$ and
Method 2 for $\pderiv{}{N_*}N(t)$;
here is a similar lemma for $\pderiv{}{N_0}N(t)$:
$$\begin{align*}
      \boxed{\pderiv{}{N_0}\esth(t)}
        &\eqd \pderiv{}{N_0 }\brs{\frac{N_*}{1+\brp{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}}
        && \text{by definition of $\esth(t)$}
      \\&= \frac{ - N_*\brp{\frac{-1}{N_0^2}}e^{-a_0 t}}
                {\brs{1+\brp{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}^2}
        && \text{by Quotient Rule}
      \\&= \brs{ \frac{e^{-a_0 t}}{N_*N_0^2}}
           \brs{\frac{N_*}{1+\brs{\frac{N_*}{N_0}-1}e^{-a_0 t}}}^2
      \\&= \brs{ \frac{e^{-a_0 t}}{N_*N_0^2}}
           \esth^2(t)
        && \text{by definition of $\esth(t)$}
    \end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    \boxed{0}
      &= \frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}\cdot0
    \\&=\frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}
         \pderiv{}{N_0}\norm{e}^2
    \\&\eqd \frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}
         \pderiv{}{N_0}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}e^2(t_n)
      && \text{by definition of $\norm{\cdot}$}
    \\&\eqd \frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}
         \pderiv{}{N_0}\sum_{n=0}^{n=10}\brs{\esth(t_n)-y_n}^2
      && \text{by definition of $e$}
    \\&= \frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}
         \sum_{n=0}^{n=10}2\brs{\esth(t_n)-y_n} \pderiv{}{N_0}\esth(t_n)
      && \text{by Chain Rule}
    \\&= \frac{N_*N_0^2}{2}
         \sum_{n=0}^{n=10}2\brs{\esth(t_n)-y_n} \brs{ \frac{e^{-a_0 t_n}}{N_*N_0^2}}\esth^2(t_n)
      && \text{by lemma}
    \\&= \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{n=10} \esth^2(t_n)\brs{\esth(t_n)-y_n} e^{-a_0 t_n} }
    \end{align*}$$

So now we have a three equation triple
$\otriple{\pderiv{}{N_h}\norm{e}^2=0}{\pderiv{}{N_0}\norm{e}^2=0}{\pderiv{}{a_0}\norm{e}^2=0}$
in a three variable triple $\otriple{N_*}{N_0}{a_0}$.
The result using [multiroot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rootSolve/versions/1.8.2.1/topics/multiroot)
from the R package [rootSolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf) is
$\otriple{N_0}{N_*}{a_0}=\otriple{18.1994673377}{256.0554740324}{0.6508899900}$.
This solution is "better" than both Methods 1 and 2 in the sense that it results in a lower *cost*:
$$\begin{array}{|c|rcl|}
  \text{Method} & cost(N_0,N_*,a_0)
\\\hline
\\1             & cost(18,252,0.6631183) &=& 31.32307
\\2             & cost(18,255.8436595023,0.6539203544) &=& 0.7140973
\\3             & cost(18.1994673377, 256.0554740324, 0.6508899900) &=& 0.4533383
\end{array}$$
[image]
Some R code supporting [Reproducible Research](https://ropensci.github.io/reproducibility-guide/sections/introduction/):

```
#---------------------------------------
# packages
#---------------------------------------
#install.packages("stats");
#install.packages("R.utils");
#install.packages("rootSolve");
 require(stats);
 require(R.utils);
 require(rootSolve);
 rm(list=objects());

#---------------------------------------
# Data
#---------------------------------------
 tdata = c(0:10)
 ydata = c(18,33,56,90,130,170,203,225,239,247,251)
 t     = seq( from=min(tdata), to=max(tdata), length=1000 )

#---------------------------------------
# Estimate Function N(t)
#---------------------------------------
 N0 = ydata[1]
 N = function(t,N0,Nh,a0)
 {
   result = Nh / ( 1 + (Nh/N0-1)*exp(-a0*t) )
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 cost = function(N0,Nh,a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) - ydata[i] )^2
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative with respect to a0 of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 Pcosta0 = function(N0, Nh, a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) )^2 *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0,Nh,a0) - ydata[i] ) *
                   ( tdata[i] * exp(-a0*tdata[i]) )
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative with respect to Nh of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 PcostNh = function(N0, Nh, a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( 1 - exp(-a0*tdata[i]) ) *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0) )^2 *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0) - ydata[i] )
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative with respect to N0 of Cost Function
#---------------------------------------
 PcostN0 = function(N0, Nh, a0)
 {
   summ = 0;
   for (i in c(1:length(tdata)))
   {
     summ = summ + ( exp(-a0*tdata[i]) ) *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0) )^2 *
                   ( N(tdata[i],N0, Nh, a0) - ydata[i] )
   }
   result = summ
 }

#---------------------------------------
# Partial derivative vector of cost
#---------------------------------------
Pcost = function(x)
{
   N0 = x[1]
   Nh = x[2]
   a0 = x[3]
   F1 = Pcosta0( N0, Nh, a0 );
   F2 = PcostNh( N0, Nh, a0 );
   F3 = PcostN0( N0, Nh, a0 );
   result = c(F1, F2, F3);
}

#---------------------------------------
# Calculate roots
#---------------------------------------
 Roots = multiroot( f=Pcost, start=c(ydata[1], ydata[11], 0.6) );
 N0 = Roots$root[1]
 Nh = Roots$root[2]
 a0 = Roots$root[3]

#---------------------------------------
# Display
#---------------------------------------
 printf("(N0, Nh, a0) = (%.10f, %.10f, %.10f) with estim.precis=%.2e\n", N0, Nh, a0, Roots$estim.precis )
 colors = c( "red" , "blue" );
 traces = c( "N(t)", "data" );
 plot ( t , N(t, N0, Nh, a0), col=colors[1], lwd=2, type='l', xlab="t", ylab="y", ylim=c(0,max(ydata)+10) )
 lines( tdata, ydata        , col=colors[2], lwd=5, type='p' )
 legend("topleft", legend=traces, col=colors, lwd=3, lty=1:1)
 grid()
```